# Tag question of ought to

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, questions, grammaticality-in-context, tag-questions

I would like to know the tag question of "ought to" is oughtn't to or shouldn't ?
For example,
He ought to have made a note of it, ________? For this sentence, the tag will be "oughtn't he?" or " shouldn't he?"

Answer (score 1):

Formally the tag would be "oughtn't he?"

"Shouldn't he" is just another question that means the same.  You could use that instead, because it means the same.

Comment: thanks a lot, have a nice day !